# Xor of random numbers or UUID

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

I'm developing data structure where each entity should have unique identifier. I'm thinking about using 64 bit random numbers or Boost UUID http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/uuid/ for this.

If I do copying of some entities I need to generate for copies new UUIDs (because otherwise some entities will have duplicate UUIDs). But updating UUIDs requires updating links between entities. So I'm thinking about uniform change to all UUID's: before copying of entities I will generate some LoadingUUID and update all UUIDs using formula:

```
NewEntityID = EntityID xor LoadingUUID
```

**The question is: will xor of two UUIDs substantially increase probability of clashing UUIDs?**

Comment: Besides, if you xor some number twice with the same number (think about copying the copy) you will get original number.

Comment: Yes! but as you can see I won't use the same LoadingUUID twice

Comment: @Rem how can we see that?  In case you missed the thrust, Cthulhu warns that after `NewEntityID = EntityID xor LoadingUUID`, another copy gives `NewNewEntityID = NewEntityID xor LoadingUUID` which is equal to `(EntityId xor LoadingUUID) xor LoadingUUID` which simplifies to `EntityId` - a collision.  Separately, if that's not a problem, `NewEntityID = ~EntityID` is likely less collision prone that any non-all-bits-set value of `LoadingUUID`.  That said, not "updating links" properly is bodgy and hackish and may be better avoided altogether.

Comment: Is just assigning 64-bit consecutive numbers as IDs not an option?

Comment: You can see this because I stated that LoadingUUID will be generate each time I need to copy entities. Also updating links is a very hard task for my system because entities parts is stored inside database and reload all data, update links and then save back again is not good thing from performance point of view

Comment: No, consecutive numbers is not an option - they clash with old ID's after copy and paste of entitites

Comment: The XOR of two random numbers from the same power-of-two range with a uniform distribution, will again be a random number with a uniform distribution in the same range. But I'm not sure this scenario satisfies all those conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If the two UUIDs have bitwise correlations, then yes, xor-ing them together will increase the probability of collisions.

Edit: Two independent UUID generators might be free of bitwise correlations, but it's hard to know for sure and it won't be anybody's design or testing goal when creating UUID generators. If they are free of correlations, then I expect that the collision probability won't increase.

In contrast, a single UUID generator is likely to have bitwise correlations between its UUID results. E.g. it might allot some of the bits to a timestamp.

Comment: I don't think UUID generator generate UUIDs with bitwise correlation

Answer (score 1):

As *harold* posted in comments The XOR of two random numbers from the same power-of-two range with a uniform distribution, will again be a random number with a uniform distribution in the same range.

I have tested with int64_t as UUID and std::mt19937_64 as UUID generator and generate 100.000 unique IDs and xor them 100 times using random IDs (resulting in total 10 million of ids). This test I run dozen of times and such scheme produces no duplicates. That is more then enough for my needs. (Number of entities is below 10-20k)

Comment: UUIDs aren't just randomly generated though, e.g. they take in your MAC address plus other hardware ID from your PC to decrease the chance of clashing with one that's generated elsewhere.